# How can the aspect ratio of a youtube movie be retrieved using Zend_Gdata_YouTube?

Tags: zend-framework, youtube

how can the aspect ratio of a youtube movie be determined from a videoEntry retrieved by Zend_Gdata_YouTube?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but am about to -- you can say:

```
$video ->getVideoThumbnails() where $video is a Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry
```

Then I will use the thumbnail's aspect ratio. The test is of course against 2 different videos with known different aspect ratios.

I will let you know if this works.

Comment: I guess there is really no way. It's basically 4/3. There is definitely a 16/9 format but I think in that case you would need a flag for widescreen VS normal. -- All the thumbnails I tried are coming as 120 x 90 anyway